# Two distinct programs running in the same JVM at the same time with the same static variable - Is that an issue?

Tags: java

I have two distinct programs running in the same JVM at the same time, both declare the same static variable:

```
private static final Location loc = Location.getLocation("myLocation");
```

Should I expect issues?

Comment: Is this variable in the same class in each case, and if so, is it loaded via the same class loader? What does its value depend on, or is it constant? More information needed....

Comment: It depends. You need to provide more info about how you run two distinct programs in one JVM and how do you know that they run in the same JVM

Comment: What `Location.getLocation("myLocation");` is returning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the method `Location.getLocation()` if you are crating the new instance of the `Location` class then there is no issue.

But if you are returning the same object then it may cause issue in case of MultiThreading then you have to get the lock before using it on the class itself.

Comment: Yes I did but what if the classes are also the same?

Comment: What does it mean? You can't create two classes in the same package. How many classes have you written?

Comment: In two different programs altogether but both programs run in the same JVM at the same time

Comment: No problem both the classes will work separately and variables are binded to the class.

Comment: It Also depends on which classloader classes have been loaded with

Comment: If, the OP is creating an instance of the same class, then they will get the same static variable

Comment: But with the same name and under the same package, they are simply packaged in two distinct jars

Comment: @Joly If the classes have the same name, package and class loader, only one of them will be used in both programs. Even if they are in separate jars.